# Set error for getJSON loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jsonp, getjson

I have the following function set up to pull in JSON data as part of a loop and am wondering how to set up an error in the event that the getJSON call fails. Any advice? Thanks much!!

```
function getJSON(){
    $.getJSON( "http://server/json.js?callback=?")
}
```

JSON is formatted like below:

```
parseJSON({
    "data" : {
        "options" : true
    }
});
```

Later the loop is called:

```
function parseJSON(data){
    // a bunch javascript events events
    setTimeout(function(){getJSON(data)}, 7000);
}
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to set the error function to the setTimeout loop. Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` loop? `setTimeout` will execute only once, 7secs after invoked

Comment: Why don't you just use the `.fail` callback of `.getJSON`, see examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: When I add the .fail() to the $.getJSON(), it fails everytime